# Integrate CMS Application with Custom ASP .Net Solution

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

Currently i am working on one custom asp .net application, client wants to integrate the application with some CMS portal.

i.e. WSS 3.0, Umbraco, SiteCore, EPiServer, N2CMS

I want some resources to analyze that what are the possible options for CMS and do the cooperative analysis.

I need some analysis document (if already exist) for pros and cons of different CMS solutions.

So, i can suggest the best option to my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking into a lot of CMS stuff recently.
EpiServer is expensive for licenses so you may want to consider an open source CMS.

Have a look at [this](http://www.cmswire.com/downloads/cms-market-share/)

Comment: I have decided to go ahead with umbraco, as i have gone through with the market share report as well as also seen that it is highest downloaded in recent past.

Also the documentation available on site is good and i am planning to buy their umbracotv subscription, finally i liked its approach of  possible to develop user control independently (not req. to inherit)  unlike DNN.

Answer (score 2):

[www.mojoportal.com](http://www.mojoportal.com) is opensource .net built upon on a variaty of databases.

Answer (score 0):

[MindTouch](http://www.mindtouch.com) is an open source Wiki / CMS system with C# core, PHP to serve up content, and a scripting language called DekiScript.  The back end code is very solid and you can integrate it with other ASP.net solutions, as you can get at the content via the C# API.

It also has database connectors for SQL, MySQL and Oracle, as well as a very nicely XML based document storage system which again is exposed via the C# API.  Currently they are working on a schema-less data store for CouchDB style functionality.